# Why Does FireFox Not Include the .xml Extension when Downloading a File?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, cross-browser, http-headers, mime-types

OK. I'm sure it does download XML files with the .xml extension, but I'm wondering what is missing in the code here to cause the .xml extenstion to be missing from the downloaded file.

Note: This works in IE 6+ (didn't try WebKit based browsers or Opera)

```
    private void GenerateXmlAttachment(string xmlInStringFormat, string fileName)
    {
    // Where fileName = "someFile.xml"
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.Charset = string.Empty;
        response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;

    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        response.AddHeader("Content-Length", xmlInStringFormat.Length.ToString());
    response.ContentType = "text/xml";          

    response.Write(xmlInStringFormat);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();

    }
```

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Can you ABSOLUTELY GUARANTEE filename has .xml on the end?

Comment: 100% ABSOLUTELY GUARANTEED. Just checked again because you made me doubt it ;)

Comment: Here's the response headers care of Live HTTP Headers:

HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.1
Date: Mon, 13 Jul 2009 17:05:14 GMT
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test.xml
Content-Length: 2040
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing:

response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);

To:

response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName));

The code works for all browsers (including Firefox which we use heavily).

Comment: @Jose. Yup that's it. I found it about 30 minutes ago on this post, http://www.webmaster-talk.com/asp-forum/35962-content-disposition-does-nto-work-firefox.html. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 7):

Solved the firefox spaces problems.
Surround your filename with quotes.

Change the code below

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
```

to

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

Comment: I prefer this solution to the accepted one, because it doesn't convert spaces to plus symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Does your filename have space in it? Firefox may have problem with that.

See this blog post for more details:

http://blog.mjjames.co.uk/2009/04/content-disposition-in-different.html