# file extension not downloading in ASP.NET 3.5 forms

Tags: c#, filestream, asp.net-3.5

I'm really baffled because on one website, my code works perfectly, and on another website, it doesn't.

The file downloads without the extension, but when I rename the downloaded file to include the extension (I add `.pdf` to the filename), it opens correctly as a PDF. I am 100% sure `bytes` and `filename` are correct, and `filename` is `report.pdf`.

Here's the original code:

```
    private void downloadByteStreamAsFile(Byte[] bytes, String fileName)
    {
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();

            //response.Flush(); //comment this or else no file returned
            response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "; size=" + bytes.Length.ToString());

            response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();

        }
    }
```

I also tried:

- using output stream [Trying to stream a PDF file with asp.net is producing a "damaged file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300729/trying-to-stream-a-pdf-file-with-asp-net-is-producing-a-damaged-file)
- removing the space after the semicolon in `Content-Disposition` [file extensions lost between browsers in asp.net c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465565/file-extensions-lost-between-browsers-in-asp-net-c-sharp-application)
- `"attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".PDF; size=" + bytes.Length.ToString());` (so now the file should be named `report.pdf.PDF` but it is still only named `report`)

Please help

Update: Code works fine in IE and Chrome, only Firefox has this issue of losing the file extension

Comment: try to use `response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");`

Comment: @Lashane : ( Nope, doesn't help. But I did figure out it is firefox only

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Does FireFox Not Include the .xml Extension when Downloading a File?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120599/why-does-firefox-not-include-the-xml-extension-when-downloading-a-file)

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120599/why-does-firefox-not-include-the-xml-extension-when-downloading-a-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This threw me for a real loop, but it turned out that only PDF files weren't being downloaded correctly, and that was because of the `Content-Type` being set. I probably could have refactored my code differently, but I liked coding it this way best because it was easiest for me to understand and debug. Here's my fixed method:

```
    private void downloadByteStreamAsFile(Byte[] bytes, String fileName)
    {
        fileName = fileName.Replace(" ", "_");

        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();

       if( fileName.Contains(".pdf")){
            fileName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName);
            //response.Flush(); //comment this or else no file returned
            response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "; size=" + bytes.Length.ToString());

            response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
        } else {
            //response.Flush(); //comment this or else no file returned
            response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "; size=" + bytes.Length.ToString());

            response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the filename in quotes.

```
response.AddHeader(
    "Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"; size=" + bytes.Length.ToString());`
```

If that works, then see if this still works for IE and Chrome and Safari. If not, add an `if` statement to conditionally add the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using IIS 7.5 with Windows Server 2008 R2 follow the code snippet below...

The code works cross browser and handles "Network Failed error" for chrome browser > 51 update

```
     // CSV Generic List    
         CSVExportGeneric<BookFxDownload> _csv = new CSVExportGeneric<BookFxDownload>(Download);
            // Convert to byte array
                                byte[] a = _csv.ExportToBytes().ToArray();
    // the lines are supposed to be in the same order
                                Response.Clear();
                                Response.Buffer = true;
                                Response.ClearHeaders();
                                Response.ClearContent();

                                //Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", fileName);
                                Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
                                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", a.Length.ToString());
//fileName = <yourname>.<extension>
                                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" +"\"" + fileName + "\"");
                                Response.Charset = "";
                                Response.OutputStream.Write(a, 0, a.Length);
                                Response.Flush();
                                Response.Close();
```